# Qt C++ QPixmap only works with absolute path, how to solve WITHOUT using Qt Resource?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, relative-path, absolute-path

I can't seem to get relative path working using Qt C++. All the answers I've found use ":/img/...", which uses Qt Resource, but is there a simpler solution?

Edit: The project folder is "C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Rectangle".

Update: `qDebug() << "Current dir:" << QDir::currentPath();` shows the "build-Rectangle-...-Debug" folder

Absolute path works : `QPixmap exitPng("C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Rectangle/img/exit.png");`

Relative path doesn't work: `QPixmap exitPng("./Rectangle/img/exit.png");`

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the current working directory of your application you run?

Comment: Relative path from where? Application install location? Find that path, and use QDir methods to combine relative path to create an absolute path.

Comment: qDebug() << "Current dir:" << QDir::currentPath(); shows the current directory to be "build-Rectangle-...-Debug". Can we set the curDir to be the place where the .cpp and .hpp files are stored (the project folder)? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths should work. Relative paths refer to the current working directory. You can confirm the path is correct by printing [QDir::currentPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath)():

```
qDebug() << "Current dir:" << QDir::currentPath();
```

Relative paths may not be what you want in some cases. If you prefer to use a path relative to the directory of the executable, you can combine your relative path to the executable path: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath.

Comment: qDebug() << "Current dir:" << QDir::currentPath();
This shows the curDir to be "build-Rectangle-...-Debug". Is there a way to set the working dir to be in the project folder, where the .cpp and .hpp files are located ?